# scraping news sites from link list in json file returning first page only

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I am using a tutorial I found ([linke](https://medium.com/@ankurjain_79625/how-did-i-scrape-news-article-using-python-6eff936b3c8c)) to scrape news sites using the python library newspaper and feedparser.

It reads the link to process from a json file and then get the articles from it. The issue was it can only get articles from the first page and doesnt iterate to the 2nd, 3rd and so on. So, I wrote a script to populate the json file with the first 50 pages of a site, eg www.site.com/page/x.

```py
{
"site0" : { "link" : "https://sitedotcom/page/0/"},
"site1" : { "link" : "https://sitedotcom/page/1/"},
"site2" : { "link" : "https://sitedotcom/page/2/"}
etc
}
```

```py
# Set the limit for number of articles to download
LIMIT = 1000000000
articles_array = []

data = {}
data['newspapers'] = {}

# Loads the JSON files with news sites
with open('thingie2.json') as data_file:
    companies = json.load(data_file)


count = 1

# Iterate through each news company
for company, value in companies.items():
    # If a RSS link is provided in the JSON file, this will be the first choice.
    # Reason for this is that, RSS feeds often give more consistent and correct data. RSS (Rich Site Summary; originally RDF Site Summary; often called Really Simple Syndication) is a type of
    # web feed which allows users to access updates to online content in a standardized, computer-readable format
    # If you do not want to scrape from the RSS-feed, just leave the RSS attr empty in the JSON file.
    if 'rss' in value:
        d = fp.parse(value['rss'])
        print("Downloading articles from ", company)
        newsPaper = {
            "rss": value['rss'],
            "link": value['link'],
            "articles": []
        }
        for entry in d.entries:
            # Check if publish date is provided, if no the article is skipped.
            # This is done to keep consistency in the data and to keep the script from crashing.
            if hasattr(entry, 'published'):
                if count > LIMIT:
                    break
                article = {}
                article['link'] = entry.link
                date = entry.published_parsed
                article['published'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(date)).isoformat()
                try:
                    content = Article(entry.link)
                    content.download()
                    content.parse()
                except Exception as e:
                    # If the download for some reason fails (ex. 404) the script will continue downloading
                    # the next article.
                    print(e)
                    print("continuing...")
                    continue
                article['title'] = content.title
                article['text'] = content.text
                article['authors'] = content.authors
                article['top_image'] =  content.top_image
                article['movies'] = content.movies
                newsPaper['articles'].append(article)
                articles_array.append(article)
                print(count, "articles downloaded from", company, ", url: ", entry.link)
                count = count + 1
    else:
        # This is the fallback method if a RSS-feed link is not provided.
        # It uses the python newspaper library to extract articles
        print("Building site for ", company)
        paper = newspaper.build(value['link'], memoize_articles=False)
        newsPaper = {
            "link": value['link'],
            "articles": []
        }
        noneTypeCount = 0
        for content in paper.articles:
            if count > LIMIT:
                break
            try:
                content.download()
                content.parse()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                print("continuing...")
                continue
            # Again, for consistency, if there is no found publish date the article will be skipped.
            # After 10 downloaded articles from the same newspaper without publish date, the company will be skipped.

            article = {}
            article['title'] = content.title
            article['authors'] = content.authors
            article['text'] = content.text
            article['top_image'] =  content.top_image
            article['movies'] = content.movies
            article['link'] = content.url
            article['published'] = content.publish_date
            newsPaper['articles'].append(article)
            articles_array.append(article)
            print(count, "articles downloaded from", company, " using newspaper, url: ", content.url)
            count = count + 1
            #noneTypeCount = 0
    count = 1
    data['newspapers'][company] = newsPaper



#Finally it saves the articles as a CSV-file.
try:
    f = csv.writer(open('Scraped_data_news_output2.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8'))
    f.writerow(['Title', 'Authors','Text','Image','Videos','Link','Published_Date'])
    #print(article)
    for artist_name in articles_array:
        title = artist_name['title']
        authors=artist_name['authors']
        text=artist_name['text']
        image=artist_name['top_image']
        video=artist_name['movies']
        link=artist_name['link']
        publish_date=artist_name['published']
        # Add each artist’s name and associated link to a row
        f.writerow([title, authors, text, image, video, link, publish_date])
except Exception as e: print(e)
```

Navigating in my browser to these sites brings up older and unique articles as expected. But when I run the script on them it returns the same articles no matter the page number. Is there something I have done wrong or have not considered ?

Comment: as i said this this is code I found online, but its to reset the count for the article number that is printed

Comment: Obviously the `link` is not used, but only for user convenience.